# Inline menu items

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want my menu items to not overlap and stay in one line as the screen size shrinks.

**This is my code:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>My menu</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <a>Main page</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <a>Second page</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <a>Third page</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You can see the problem in the above image:

[image: overlap problem]

Comment: Then you will probably have to either reduce the font-size, or the margins/paddings. But maybe the whole thing should not be a row/col construct to begin with; BS has https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navbar/ after all.

Comment: Guys, I wanted to implement this with a dropdown menu, but the site manager does not accept this

Comment: For keeping your menu items on a single line on small displays, then as @CBroe said, reduce the font size. You could set the font size for the text using a calc function along the lines of `font-size: calc((100vw – 90px)/16)`.

Comment: How about using `col-12` instead of `col-auto`?